# When can `typename` be used with identifiers that unambiguously refer to a type?

Tags: c++, syntax, language-lawyer

Normally, `typename` is used to disambiguate between cases where an identifier may refer to a type, or may refer to something else:

```
template<class T>
void foo(typename T::type value) {
   // ...
}
```

#### When can `typename` be used when an identifier is already a type?

**1.** Can it be used if there's already a class with this name?

```
class MyClass{};

void foo(typename MyClass value) {}
```

**2.** Can it be used with a template parameter that's declared as a type?

```
template<class T>
void foo(typename T value) {}
```

**3.** Can it be used with inner classes that are unambiguously types?

```
class A {
   public:
    class B {};
};

// Compiles; no typename necessary
void foo(A::B value) {} 
// This compiles too on gcc and msvc
void bar(typename A::B value) {}
```

#### Compiler interpretation

**Case 1:** MSVC considers this OK; gcc and clang throw an error

**Case 2:** MSVC considers this OK; gcc and clang throw an error

**Case 3:** `A::B` is unambiguously a type, but gcc and clang now permit the use of `typename`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyword `typename` is only permitted by the C++ [syntax](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/gram) to introduce a [template type parameter](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.param#1), or [before a qualified name](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.res#nt:typename-specifier), i.e. something containing the `::` token.

So your #1 and #2 are ill-formed because `MyClass` and `T` are unqualified names, not containing any `::`.

Before a qualified name, the `typename` token is:

- not allowed by the grammar before [a base class name](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.derived#nt:class-or-decltype) in the head of a class definition, or [in combination with the `class`, `struct`, or `union` keywords](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.type.elab#nt:elaborated-type-specifier); a qualified name is always treated as a type in these contexts
- otherwise required, if the qualified name is [dependent and a member of an unknown specialization](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.dep)
- otherwise optional, whether within a template declaration or not

C++17 [temp.res]/3,5,6:

> When a *qualified-id* is intended to refer to a type that is not a member of the current instantiation and its *nested-name-specifier* refers to a dependent type, it shall be prefixed by the keyword `typename`, forming a *typename-specifier*. ...
>
> A qualified name used as the name in a *class-or-decltype* (Clause [class.derived]) or an *elaborated-type-specifier* is implicitly assumed to name a type, without the use of the `typename` keyword. In a *nested-name-specifier* that immediately contains a *nested-name-specifier* that depends on a template parameter, the *identifier* or *simple-template-id* is implicitly assumed to name a type, without the use of the `typename` keyword. [*Note:* The `typename` keyword is not permitted by the syntax of these constructs. - *end note*]
>
> If, for a given set of template arguments, a specialization of a template is instantiated that refers to a *qualified-id* that denotes a type or a class template, and the *qualified-id* refers to a member of an unknown specialization, the *qualified-id* shall either be prefixed by `typename` or shall be used in a context in which it implicitly names a type as described above.

So your #3 is well-formed, even though the name does not depend on a template parameter and isn't even in a template declaration.

Note C++20 will add [many more contexts](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.res#5) where `typename` is optional even with a dependent name, because it's possible to unambiguously determine from the contexts that the name can only mean a type.

Answer (score 1):

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/typename)

> Usage:
>
> - In a template declaration, typename can be used as an alternative to class to declare type template parameters and template template parameters (since C++17).
> - Inside a declaration or a definition of a template, typename can be used to declare that a dependent name is a type.
> - Inside a requirements for type requirements (since C++20)

So I would say that you have no guaranties that case 1 and case 2 will compile. As they do not fall into any of these three usage cases.

And for case 3, let's see what [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name) has to say about that:

> The keyword `typename` may only be used in this way before qualified names (e.g. T::x), but the names need not be dependent.
>
> The keyword typename must only be used in template declarations and definitions and only in contexts in which dependent names can be used. This excludes explicit specialization declarations and explicit instantiation declarations.(until C++11)
>
> The keyword typename can be used even outside of templates. (since C++11)

So as there is no template in your example, case 3 should be guarantied to work only since C++11

And indeed a test program compiled OK with ***g++ -std=c++11*** but issued this warning without ***-std=c++11***

> warning: 'typename' occurs outside of a template
>         [-Wc++11-extensions]

Comment: Linking to cppreference under the name of "the standard" is at best incorrect.